# Terminology: Name for undirected graph with two types of vertices, A and B, where all edges are A<->B, and no edges are A<->A or B<->B

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Something like the image below, anyone know what it's called?

[image: graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a **[bipartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)** (or **2-colored**) graph.